# BlueTooth audio capturing using airpod microphone

Tags: ios, voip, audiosession

How to set audio session category so that external Bluetooth airpod device can record audio using airpod microphone and works flowless with other bluetooth device as well. Here is my code.

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

/*
 optimum to minimize delay, must put a software resampler to deal with 8khz
 */
NSError *error;
[audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:8000.0 error:&error];

if([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue>=10.0)
{
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP
                        error:&error];
}
else
{
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                  withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                        error:&error];
}
```